# Drupal 8 - adding body class based on taxonomy term or other

Tags: drupal, themes, preprocessor, drupal-8

Building a site in Drupal 8, using classy subtheme. Run into a puzzling theming issue - adding body class to html.html.twig based on a taxonomy term on that node.

Themers use this to customize page display, in my case using it to define a few sections of my site so I can change color and format.

I have tried some preprocess functions I saw on google but to no result.

Has anyone else run into and solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get all fields of the node and check for whatever you need:

```
\Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getParameter('node')->toArray();
```

In your .theme file you can use the html preprocess hook:

```
function your_theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $body_classes = [];
  $nodeFields = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getParameter('node')->toArray();

  // if something, then set $body_classes to something.

  $variables['attributes']['class'] += $body_classes;
}
```

And then in your html twig template add the attributes to the body element:

```
<body{{ attributes }}>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I put that code in my .theme file (my theme name in correct place)

But there is already the classy body class code in the html.html.twig file, when I apply your code I get a white screen.


 This code is in the twig template: 

'<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>'

Comment: I also don't know how to comment here with my code highlighted :(

Comment: What "<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>" does is that it adds the defined "body_classes" to whatever classes are already there in the attributes variable. So theoretically it should work too. You could try and debug with "var_dump" or "kint" (if you have the devel module enabled). You can also var dump directly in the twig template: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html But you have to enable twig debugging in your services.yml

Comment: Usually (from my experience with Drupal 8) a white screen has something to do with exhausted php memory, so you could also double check your logic in the preprocess function. Maybe you used some never ending loop or so? A look in the php/server logs might help too.

Answer (score 1):

With the answer of [Frank Drebin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4388689/frank-drebin) I get a PHP fatal error (Unsupported operand types) with the "+=" operand. If you want to add the node ID and node type to your body class, you can use this code for example:

```
// Add the node ID and node type to the body class

$body_classes = [];
$nodeFields = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getParameter('node')->toArray();

if (is_array($nodeFields) && count($nodeFields) > 0) {
    if (isset($nodeFields['nid'])) {
        $body_classes[] = 'node-' . $nodeFields['nid'][0]['value'];
    }
    if (isset($nodeFields['type'])) {
        $body_classes[] = $nodeFields['type'][0]['target_id'];
    }
}

$variables['attributes']['class'] = $body_classes;
```